# Office Addin / Word Addin .. replace paragraph with a custom icon

Tags: javascript, office-addins, office-automation, word-addins

i try write a word addin with replaces some paragraphs with a custom icon.

You can imagine it as a collapse/expand function.

The original paragraph content should be accessible in the taskpanel on click onto this icon.

I already can list and filter all paragraphs i want.

At first i tryed it with insertContentControl but the text property is read-only and i'm not sure how to replace the style so it looks like a simple icon.

```
for (let i = 0; i < paragraphs.items.length; i++) {
      let contentControl = paragraphs.items[i].insertContentControl();
      contentControl.tag = "forTesting";
      contentControl.title = "Test1";
      contentControl.appearance = "Tags";
      contentControl.color = "blue";
}
```

I need some hint or you can call it starting point for implementing the descripted behavior.